# Google checkout flags parsing error when using default tax tables

Tags: magento, google-checkout

I'm having issues using the default google checkout integration in magento.

I want to send my own tax data to google checkout, but when I enable the default tax tables, magento returns the following error:

Google Checkout: Error parsing XML; message from parser is: Missing element (eu-area, postal-area, us-country-area, us-state-area, us-zip-area, world-area) in: checkout-shopping-cart/checkout-flow-support/merchant-checkout-flow-support/tax-tables/alternate-tax-tables/alternate-tax-table/alternate-tax-rules/alternate-tax-rule/tax-area

I've googled this, and he only solution I can come up with is that the store postcode must be set in 'manage tax rates'. I have done this, but am still getting the error.

Has anybody else had issues with this, and found a suitable solution?